# Convert JSON to an array/map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, loops

I have a JSON response that consists of the time a user plays an audio file. For each audio session I have:

```
   {"session": {"checkpoints": [
   {"status": "started", "position": 0, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T16:55:37.795Z"}, 
   {"status": "paused", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T16:58:53.917Z"}, 
   {"status": "stopped", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T17:01:04.230Z"},
   {"status": "closed", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T17:01:04.250Z"}], "totalTime": 195}}
```

I want to map all the totalTime values and find the max value. What is the best way to do this?
what i did initially is :

```
      let maxValue = 0
      let data = JSON.parse(audios).data
      for (let totalTime in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(totalTime)) {
          let value = data[totalTime]
          if (value > maxValue) {
            maxValue = value
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: `var timeArray = []; data.forEach(item => emptyArray.push(item.totalTime.parseInt())); console.log(timeArray.max)` 100% sure it could be smaller than this using filter but im too lazy to figure that one out lol

Comment: Two questions: 1) why what you tried haven't worked?; 2) How exactly your entries are formatted? (As you've shown there, it looks like a field of an object. So each entry is in a field of the same object or is each entry in its own object, each one with the field 'audio'?).

Comment: `console.log( JSON.parse(audios).data.map(x=>+x.totalTime).filter(x=>!x).reduce((acc,x)=>Math.max(acc,x)) )`

Comment: @KevinHernandez 100% sure `item.totalTime.parseInt()` will throw `Uncaught TypeError: item.totalTime.parseInt is not a function`

Comment: I would not believe you will do it faster than the way you do now. Only if the JSON audios are sorted already by totalTime ascending or descending, you could take only last or first value. So if there is any query generating your data, then make it order by totalTime desc in first instance.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `var timeArray = []; data.forEach(item => emptyArray.push(parseInt(item.totalTime))); console.log(timeArray.max)`

Comment: @PedroLima we can see that his code doesn't work.  Improper use of `let totalTime in data` that's iterating over all keys and then data[totalTime], which doesn't actually retrieve the toatlTime property

Comment: Made a typo: console.log( JSON.parse(audios).data.map(x=>+x.totalTime).filter(x=>!!x).reduce((acc,x)=>Math.max(acc,x)) )

Comment: I have updated the post with more info

Comment: @user120242 with both questions I'm trying to solve the same mystery (for me, at least): How exactly is OP's initial data formatted? Their exemple is not clear for me because there actually is a case of entry data that would work with their code. That would be `{ time1: 2000, time2: 3200, time3: 2800 }`, which is improbable, but possible. Since their entry exemple and their code didn't match, I was wondering where exactly did they got confused.

Comment: @JazabC., so I assume you have multiple entries like that in a array?

Comment: @JazabC. your array has only one totalTime value.  Looks like Pedro was right.  Are you making multiple requests that you want to find the max value for?

Comment: you need to use `data.session.totalTime`

Comment: Please show the structure of your data clearly.

Answer (score -1):

You can get session with max `totalTime` like this

```js
// created 2 sessions, with different totalTime as example
const data = [{
    "session": {
      "checkpoints": [{
          "status": "started",
          "position": 0,
          "createdAt": "2020-02-20T16:55:37.795Z"
        },
        {
          "status": "paused",
          "position": 195,
          "createdAt": "2020-02-20T16:58:53.917Z"
        },
        {
          "status": "stopped",
          "position": 195,
          "createdAt": "2020-02-20T17:01:04.230Z"
        },
        {
          "status": "closed",
          "position": 195,
          "createdAt": "2020-02-20T17:01:04.250Z"
        }
      ],
      "totalTime": 195
    }
  },
  {
    "session": {
      "checkpoints": [{
          "status": "started",
          "position": 0,
          "createdAt": "2020-02-20T16:55:37.795Z"
        },
        {
          "status": "paused",
          "position": 195,
          "createdAt": "2020-02-20T16:58:53.917Z"
        },
        {
          "status": "stopped",
          "position": 195,
          "createdAt": "2020-02-20T17:01:04.230Z"
        },
        {
          "status": "closed",
          "position": 195,
          "createdAt": "2020-02-20T17:01:04.250Z"
        }
      ],
      "totalTime": 193
    }
  }
]

const maxSession = data.sort((a, b) => a.totalTime - b.totalTime)[0]
console.log('maxSession', maxSession)
```

Comment: How can I get just the totalTime value alone?

Comment: `totalTime` is a property of `session`, so I think what you want is `const maxSession = data.sort((a, b) => a.session.totalTime - b.session.totalTime)[0].session.totalTime`

Comment: Thank you makes much more sense now! but what was wrong with my original implementation?

Comment: You are using `for ( ... in ... )`, but you really wanted `for ( ... of ... )`. `for...in` is used to loop through the properties of an object, while `for...of` is used to iterate through the elements of an iterator. (Array is the most common type of iterator, but there are others.)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'm assuming you have multiple entries like the one you've given as exemple, and they are all in an array. So it would be something like:

```js
var data = [
{"session": {"checkpoints": [
   {"status": "started", "position": 0, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T16:55:37.795Z"}, 
   {"status": "paused", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T16:58:53.917Z"}, 
   {"status": "stopped", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T17:01:04.230Z"},
   {"status": "closed", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T17:01:04.250Z"}], "totalTime": 195}},
{"session": {"checkpoints": [
   {"status": "started", "position": 0, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T16:55:37.795Z"}, 
   {"status": "paused", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T16:58:53.917Z"}, 
   {"status": "stopped", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T17:01:04.230Z"},
   {"status": "closed", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T17:01:04.250Z"}], "totalTime": 195}},
{"session": {"checkpoints": [
   {"status": "started", "position": 0, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T16:55:37.795Z"}, 
   {"status": "paused", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T16:58:53.917Z"}, 
   {"status": "stopped", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T17:01:04.230Z"},
   {"status": "closed", "position": 195, "createdAt": "2020-02- 
   20T17:01:04.250Z"}], "totalTime": 195}}
]
```

If I'm correct, this is what you want to do:

1. Sort your array:

`var sorted = data.sort((a, b) => b.session.totalTime - a.session.totalTime);`

To each pair of objects, you will access the value you want to sort your array based on. Noticed I've inverted `b` and `a` in the subtraction. That's because you want to sort it downwards, so the greater value will come first.

2. Take the first entry, which will be the one with the greatest totalTime:

`var entry = sorted[0];`

3. Extract the desired value from the entry:

`var maxTotalTime = entry.session.totalTime;
console.log(maxTotalTime);`

---

I've shown the steps above because you requested for the best solution, but here is how you can correct the code you were trying to work with:

```
  let maxValue = 0
  let data = JSON.parse(audios).data
  for (let entry of data) {
      let value = entry.session.totalTime;
      if (value > maxValue) {
        maxValue = value;
      }
  }
```